# Java Linkage Error JAX-WS

Tags: java, jboss, jax-ws, java-6

I am getting this Error while Trying to use WebServices. I googled for it and found that it occurs because different versions of same class files maybe present or some conflict occurs. I tried giving an endorsed Directory path while running Web Application, still no luck. The environment I am using is JDK 1.6.0.20 and JBoss 5.0.:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, com/abc/amservice/AMService, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, javax/xml/ws/Service, have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature
    com.abc.amservice.AMService.<init>(AMService.java:48)
    com.abcx.accessmanager.plugin.provider.webservice.ServiceConnection.createAndInitializeNewService(ServiceConnection.java:103)
    com.abcx.accessmanager.plugin.provider.webservice.ServiceConnection.getAMService(ServiceConnection.java:91)
    com.abcx.accessmanager.plugin.provider.webservice.ServiceConnection.createNewServicePort(ServiceConnection.java:136)
    com.abcx.accessmanager.plugin.provider.webservice.ServiceConnection.getWebServicePort(ServiceConnection.java:69)
    com.abcx.accessmanager.plugin.provider.webservice.AuthenticationProviderWebService.getWebServicePort(AuthenticationProviderWebService.java:536)
    com.abcx.accessmanager.plugin.provider.webservice.AuthenticationProviderWebService.authenticateUser(AuthenticationProviderWebService.java:80)
    com.abcx.accessmanager.plugin.provider.validator.ValidatingAuthenticationProvider.authenticateUser(ValidatingAuthenticationProvider.java:59)
    com.abcx.accessmanager.plugin.api.AccessManagementServiceConnector.authenticateUser(AccessManagementServiceConnector.java:61)
    com.qwe.spring.security.MyAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(MyAuthenticationProvider.java:33)
    org.springframework.security.providers.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:188)
    org.springframework.security.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:46)
    org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:82)
    org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:259)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247662/xpath-class-resolution-in-jboss5).

In short: make sure that you do not deploy another `javax.xml.namespace.*` package, rely on the one that is shipped with Java 6

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that can help you:

1 - Change Jboss version at runtime. Download the Jboss again, your version can be cracked, it's very common. So set your Jboss runtime in Eclipse according your installation like as: "C:\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as".

OR

2 - Just remove the lib wsdl4j.jar at build path, if viable in your case.